# Why i am not able to read / as a single character in my code?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{ 
    char name[50]; 

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("filename.opt","r+");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("error in opening file");
        return (1);
    }   
    long n=ftell(fp);

    printf("%ld\t",n);
    char ch=fgetc(fp);
    printf("%c\n",ch);
    n=ftell(fp);
    printf("%ld\t",n);
    ch=fgetc(fp);
    printf("%c\n",ch);
    n=ftell(fp);
    printf("%ld\t",n);
    ch=fgetc(fp);
    printf("%c\n",ch);
    fseek(fp,-1,1);
    n=ftell(fp);
    printf("%ld\t",n);
    ch=fgetc(fp);
    printf("%c",ch);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

input string in .opt file is like /UGTMN....

output I got is like below

```
0    /
0    U
1    T
1    U  ......>
```

1. how it is actually taking. Is o/p varies if we use.opt file generated  from     different operating system(say linux) and compile the code in the windows.
2. when i go back after initial reading it shows different character to   previous one? see.....>
   IF any one knows please help me!!!

Comment: debugger, printfs, any research?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: [fgetc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) returns an `int`

Comment: When you fail to open a file, it is extremely useful to tell the user why: `const char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "filename.opt"; FILE *fp=fopen(path, "r+"); if(fp==NULL) { perror(path); exit(1);}`  `perror` will print the filename and the reason it failed to open on stderr.

Comment: Do not pass an integer literal as the third argument to `fseek()`, as no significance for any particular value is specified.  Instead, use one of the macros defined for this purpose (`SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR`, or `SEEK_END`).  The values to which these macros expand are not specified.

Comment: Do check the return values of your function calls for return values indicating errors.

Comment: "Why i am not able to read / as a single character in my code?" and the first value read was a `'/'` as you report output was "0    /".  Looks like code is reading `'/'` as a single character.  So what is the real problem/question?

Comment: Even i replaced third argument in the fseek  by SEEK_cur also i got the

Comment: actually i want output like   0    /   1   U     2   T ....; like this .Because i want file pointer takes  each character separately including  '/'   and i got the output as i required for all  remaining .opt files .But only this file iam unable to get .I want to know what is the reason behind that opt file.

Comment: Hi chux in the output we have n-vale   character value;   where n-value is character pointer which starts from 0 i.e starting character of the file and its respective character value. here for both characters '/' and  'U' it's character point is 0 only.